# CSS File Import Fails when using Path in ClojureScript Project

Tags: css, clojurescript, reagent, electric-clojure

I am working on an Electric Clojure project and I need to import a `CSS` file to style my application.
I add styles using `dom/element` and it works but the code looks so crowded. What is the best way to import a `CSS` file into `ClojureScript` and apply the styles to the `dom` and `reagent` components?

I tried to import a CSS file into a `Clojurescript` project with Hiccup link:

```clj
[:link {:href "material-ui-test/src/app/main.css", :rel "stylesheet"}]]
```

Finally, I want to import `CSS` files of `React` components into the project.

Answer (score 0):

`(dom/link (dom/props {:rel :stylesheet :href "/todo-list.css"}))`, there's a working example in the starter app [here](https://github.com/hyperfiddle/electric-starter-app/blob/371423397e0b2b7c34216260cd679858dabffeea/src/app/todo_list.cljc#L58)